# Facebook Header doesn't work

Tags: facebook, image, header

Why this Facebook header's  doesn't work?

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100001241265117">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="346433102099273">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.fontedelucro.com.br">
<meta property="og:title" content="Fonte de Lucro - Seu negócio na internet">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Fonte de Lucro - Seu negócio na internet">
<meta property="og:description" content="Blog relacionado a negócios na internet em geral. E-commerce,Programa de afiliados,Novidades entre outros">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.fontedelucro.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dolar50.gif">
<meta property="og:locale" content="pt_br">
```

When i put the url in post, the header image not show.

The page is http://www.fontedelucro.com.br.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this tool to check what is going wrong : http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fontedelucro.com.br

Aparently only the image is wrong.

EDITED:

One more thing. If you tried to share your url before you setted the header, facebook will cache the headers or the non-headers. So, you need to use the Facebook Object Debugger to force clear this cache.